# panzoom.js and paper.js compensating point for scale

Tags: javascript, paperjs

The intent is to place an image on a canvas, draw on it while being able to pan and zoom.  I’m using panzoom.js and paper.js

What works....
I can pan and zoom the canvas.
I can draw on the canvaas

What doesn’t work...
once I zoom - things go bad.  the paper "point" no longer appears to correspond with the mouse arrow.  after zooming in, some sort of factor seems to be off and what is drawn on the screen is some distance away from the pointer

How do i compensate the paper.js point for the zoom factor on the canvas?

The HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="myImage" width="612" height="792px">
        <img id="page" src="page.png" width="100%" height="100%">
    </canvas>
</div>
<img id="first" src="page.png" width="612" height="792" style="display:none">
```

For panzoom.js..

```
var $panzoom = $('#myImage').panzoom();

$panzoom.parent().on('mousewheel.focal', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
    $panzoom.panzoom('zoom', zoomOut, {
        increment: 0.1,
        animate: false,
        focal: e
    });
  });
```

and for paper.js...

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myImage">

var raster = new Raster('first');
raster.position = view.center;
raster.scale(1);

tool.maxDistance = 10;

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    var circle = new Path.Circle({
        center: event.middlePoint,
        radius: event.delta.length / 2
    });
    circle.fillColor = 'black';
}
```